# LibGDX - Custom Click Listener?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to make my own Button class, that will have a Sprite, and whenever i touch it it will grow or rotate, etc, the class will have also a Draw and Update function.

To check if I touch it i can check if the sprite rectangle contains the position of the touch in the touchdown and touchup method of the screen class.

I don't want to do that, i want to make something like android button click listener, is that possible?

Something like

```
myCoolButton.setOnClickListener(new CoolButtonClassClickListener(

public void OnTouchDown()  {

}

public void OnTouchUp()   {
}
});
```

Is possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are actually asking? You can look at the source on how the EventListener and its subclasses work. I'm not sure what is the problem here. You should also tell us what approaches and code you have tried

Comment: I've didn't try anything because I don't know how, that's why i've asked. I want to make something like a click listener, as I said, just like the android button one..

Comment: Then make your button take listeners. When the button gets clicked, you call the listeners. You can look at how LibGDX does it. Not sure why you want your own button though. You should also try before you ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can, that's exactly what I did too.

```
public interface FFListener
{
    public void onClick(FFListenerButton flb);
}
```

And

```
public class FFListenerButton extends FFButton
{
    private FFListener ffListener;

    public FFListenerButton(Rectangle bounds, CharSequence text, FFListener ffListener)
    {
        super(bounds, text);
        this.ffListener = ffListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void action()
    {
        ffListener.onClick(this);
    }
}
```

And

```
public abstract class FFButton 
{
    private Rectangle bounds;
    private CharSequence text;
    private boolean selected;
    private boolean hidden;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean disabled;

    public FFButton(Rectangle bounds, CharSequence text)
    {
        this.bounds = bounds;
        this.text = text;
        this.hidden = false;
        this.active = false;
        this.disabled = false;
    }

    protected abstract void action();

    public void execute()
    {
        if(disabled == false)
        {
            action();
        }
    }


    public boolean contains(float x, float y)
    {
        return bounds.contains(x, y);
    }

    public float x()
    {
        return bounds.x;
    }

    public float y()
    {
        return bounds.y;
    }

    public float width()
    {
        return bounds.width;
    }

    public float height()
    {
        return bounds.height;
    }

    public void drawBounds(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer)
    {
        if(hidden != true)
        {
        shapeRenderer.rect(x(), y(), width(), height(), 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public FFButton setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        return this;
    }

    public void drawText(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        if(hidden != true)
        {
            Resources.bitmapFont.draw(batch, getText(), x()+(width()/8), y()+height()*0.75f); //black magic, please adjust
        }
    }

    public boolean getSelected()
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public FFButton setSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isActive()
    {
        return active;
    }

    public FFButton setActive(boolean active)
    { 
        this.active = active;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isHidden()
    {
        return hidden;
    }

    public FFButton setHidden(boolean hidden)
    {
        this.hidden = hidden;
        return this;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return bounds;
    }

    public boolean isDisabled()
    {
        return disabled;
    }

    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled)
    {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }
}
```

Although technically this uses a Rectangle and uses ShapeRenderer to render it, it really isn't hard to swap it out for a Sprite. Afterwards, you can just ask with contains whether the click is contains, and call execute() from the outside if it does.

Create like this:

```
backButton = new FFListenerButton(new Rectangle(400, 20, 60, 30), "Back", this);
```

And handle events like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(FFListenerButton clb)
{
    if(clb == backButton)
    {
        backButtonPressed();
    }
    else if(clb == selectButton)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And this used my AbstractMenuScreen class to delegate the events to the buttons if they were clicked:

```
public abstract class AbstractMenuScreen extends BaseScreen
{
    protected List<FFButton> buttons;

    public AbstractMenuScreen(List<FFButton> buttons)
    {
        this.buttons = buttons; 
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta)
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Resources.batch.setProjectionMatrix(Resources.normalProjection);

        Resources.batch.begin();
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            FFButton b = buttons.get(i);
            if(b.isHidden() != true)
            {
                b.drawText(Resources.batch);
            }
        }

        Resources.batch.end();

        Resources.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Resources.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            FFButton b = buttons.get(i);
            if(b.isHidden() != true)
            {
                b.drawBounds(Resources.shapeRenderer);
            }
        }
        Resources.shapeRenderer.end();

        Resources.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        Resources.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            FFButton b = buttons.get(i);
            if(b.isHidden() != true)
            {
                if(b.isActive() == true)
                {
                    b.drawBounds(Resources.shapeRenderer);
                }
            }
        }
        Resources.shapeRenderer.end();

        Resources.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        Resources.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            FFButton b = buttons.get(i);
            if(b.isHidden() != true)
            {
                if(b.getSelected() == true)
                {
                    b.drawBounds(Resources.shapeRenderer);
                }
            }
        }
        Resources.shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
    {
        float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(windowWidth, screenX);
        float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(windowHeight, screenY);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            if(buttons.get(i).contains(pointerX, pointerY))
            {
                if(buttons.get(i).isHidden() != true)
                {
                    buttons.get(i).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
    {
        float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(windowWidth, screenX);
        float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(windowHeight, screenY);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
        {
            if(buttons.get(i).contains(pointerX, pointerY) && buttons.get(i).getSelected())
            {
                buttons.get(i).execute();
            }
            buttons.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

And you extended from this like this:

```
public class ServerClientPickScreen extends AbstractMenuScreen implements FFListener
{
    private FFButton backButton;
    private FFButton clientButton;
    private FFButton serverButton;

    public ServerClientPickScreen()
    {
        super(new ArrayList<FFButton>());
        backButton = new FFListenerButton(new Rectangle(400, 20, 60, 30), "Back", this);
        clientButton = new FFListenerButton(new Rectangle(260, 140, 80, 30), "Client", this);
        serverButton = new FFListenerButton(new Rectangle(140, 140, 80, 30), "Server", this);
        buttons.add(backButton);
        buttons.add(clientButton);
        buttons.add(serverButton);
 ....
```

Comment: Is funny that my class is called MMButton haha :) Thank you. Upvote & accepted.

Comment: FF stands for "Furball Flurry", after my exams I might tinker with it a little more to make it more fun and actually release it on Google Play :P

Comment: ..if I ever will.. -.-

Comment: Nope. Needed more polishing and I kinda never got to it. I'd rewrite it from scratch if I did, because I kinda got better at things since then. How about you?

Comment: Stopped with game dev, because I got hired in september as mobile app developer.. I don't regret this because I can start again any game, and in my country there are not as many game dev companies :)

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonUp = new TextButton("", styleUpButton); //** Button text and style **//
   buttonUp.setPosition(84, 40);
   buttonUp.setHeight(64); 
   buttonUp.setWidth(64); 
   buttonUp.addListener(new InputListener() {
   public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)   {
HereYouHaveToCallMethodYouNeed();
   return true;
}
   public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
//  Here may be onemore method.
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't use scene2d. And TextButton class is not what i want to do.